# ¿Es posible ordenarle al bucle foreach que busque en una sola parte del array?

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Una vez mas espero esten saludables. Esta pregunta se relaciona mucho a mi pregunta anterior (La cual he podido resolver gracias a Dios).

Bien, mi pregunta anterior era: *¿Como puedo hacer para declarar una variable con el valor de un elemento de mi array?*

Mi nueva pregunta es la presentada arriba del todo. Cito ejemplo:

```
foreach ($almacen as $key_array => $datos) {
            $ernor = $datos->ernor;
            $created = $datos->created;
            $result = $datos->result;
                foreach ($datos as $clave => $info) {
                    $avatar = $info->avatar;
                    $name = $info->name;
                    $country = $info->country;
                    $imageRating = $info->imageRating;
                    $ivao = $info->ivao;
                    $data = $info->dataAirline;

                }
                    foreach ($info as $clavedos => $lentejas) {
                        $totalHoursFlights = $lentejas->totalHoursFlights;
                        $callsign = $lentejas->callsign;    
                        }

        }
```

Y este es un pedazo de mi array.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1023
                    [name] => Juan Camilo V.
                    [country] => CO
                    [avatar] => https://www.uesva.com/avatar/icons.php?o=17&i=1023_sheacyPnckHzoGacTAkJDwPFRjZMRp1588229451
                    [scoreRating] => 104,00
                    [pilotRating] => Estudiante
                    [imageRating] => https://www.uesva.com/avatar/icons.php?o=16&i=91_kYxDuERnbE1587976704
                    [lastLoginDate] => 2020-05-01
                    [lastLoginTime] => 06:35:11
                    [UesvaRegisteredDate] => 2020-03-29
                    [UesvaRegisteredTimee] => 21:10:49
                    [ivao] => 494761
                    [vatsim] => 1458554
                    [dataAirline] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [callsign] => AVC100
                            [totalFlights] => 2
                            [totalFlightsRegular] => 2
                            [totalFlightsCharter] => 0
                            [totalFlightsEvent] => 0
                            [totalFlightsTour] => 0
                            [totalFlightsTransfer] => 0
                            [totalHoursFlights] => 1:08:57
                            [totalHoursOnline] => 2:12:44
                            [totalMilesFlown] => 440
                            [totalPassengersCarried] => 279
                            [totalPassengersFirstClass] => 0
                            [totalPassengersBusiness] => 19
                            [totalPassengersEconomic] => 260
                            [totalCargoCarried] => 98.673
                            [lastFlightDate] => 30/04/2020
                            [monthFlights] => 0
                            [monthFlightsRegular] => 0
                            [monthFlightsCharter] => 0
                            [monthFlightsEvent] => 0
                            [monthFlightsTour] => 0
                            [monthFlightsTransfer] => 0
                            [monthHoursFlights] => 00:00:00
                            [monthHoursOnline] => 00:00:00
                            [monthMilesFlown] => 0
                            [monthPassengersCarried] => 0
                            [monthPassengersFirstClass] => 0
                            [monthPassengersBusiness] => 0
                            [monthPassengersEconomic] => 0
                            [monthCargoCarried] => 0
                        )

                )
```

Entonces.. Una vez citados estos ejemplos... ¿Es posible ordenarle a mi `foreach()` que solo busque dentro del elemento `[dataAirline]`?(Estuve buscando en toda la documentacion de PHP y no encontré nada. Quizá uds me puedan ayudar).

Gracias de antemano, cuidense.

Comment: Estás confundiendo términos. Eso que presentas es un objeto, no un array. De hecho no necesitas un for para recorrerlo, pues ya tiene sus propiedades y solo necesitas acceder a ellas directamente.

Comment: Lo siento mucho, tienes razón. Al no usar el segundo parametro de `json_decode()` me devuelve un objeto. Intentare aplicar tus correcciones. Muchisimas gracias por pasarte. Espero tengas lindo dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es sacar el valor de callsign, totalHoursFlights, etc., puedes hacerlo directo

```
$callsign = $info->dataAirline->callsign;
```

Esto tomando en cuenta que hablas de este foreach:

```
foreach ($info as $clavedos => $lentejas) {
    $totalHoursFlights = $lentejas->totalHoursFlights;
    $callsign = $lentejas->callsign;    
}
```

Así podrás quitar el foreach de $clavedos y hacer asignación directa

Comment: Gracias Deilusia. Ya mismo intento. Muchisimas gracias, soy nuevo :D

Comment: ¿Sabes de algun sitio web/cursito online en el que pueda mejorar y aprender mas?

Comment: Funciono a la perfeccion! GENIO/A

Comment: Hay cursos bastante buenos y de todos los niveles en Udemy y Coursera, en lo personal se me hacen buenas plataformas para agarrar camino.